# print contributors to prediction in adaboost model built in R

Tags: r, adaboost

I have an 'ada' model that is trained using the R package for ada, and gives predictions.

```
> class(Model)
[1] "ada"
> predict(Model,testdata,type="prob")[,2]
0.54
```

However, for a given row in 'testdata', I was wondering if there is any way to print out the top most contributors from the attributes, which affected the prediction.

When I print out the model using `Modelname$model`, I get a bunch of numbers, but I'm not too sure of how to make sense of it.